# Cómo puedo generar 2 vistas pdf con la librería Dompdf?

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Hasta el momento llevo intentando esto:

```
  $collection = collect(['FacturaEpsPdf.facturaEps', 'FacturaEpsPdf.FacturaEpsProcedimiento']);

            foreach ($collection as $value) {
                $pdf = PDF::loadView($value, $data);
                return    $pdf->stream('facturaEps.pdf');
            }
```

Comment: Esto no es programación bajo nivel. Es php, no assembly. Y trata de ampliar tu pregunta, por favor. Explícanos mejor qué quieres que pase y por qué lo que has hecho hasta ahora no funciona de esa forma. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.